# PHP 7.1.2 cannot Gmake : Zend Error

Tags: solaris, php, gnu-make, sparc

I use Solaris 11.3 Sparc 64 bit, Mysql Enterprise Advance 5.7.1, Apache 2.4.25 and PHP 7.1.2

I configure PHP with following parameter.

```
export CC="gcc -m64"
export CFLAGS="-std=gnu99"
./configure --prefix=/opt/app/php --with-openssl=/opt/app/openssl --datadir=/opt/app/php --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=apache --with-fpm-group=apache --with-pcre-regex=/opt/app/pcre --with-apxs2=/opt/app/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysqli=/opt/app/mysql/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-sock=/opt/app/mysql/mysql/socket/mysql.sock --with-libxml-dir=/opt/app/libxml2 --with-bz2 --with-zlib
```

I got the following error.

```
ld: warning: file /usr/gcc/4.8/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.11/4.8.2/libgcc.a(_clzdi2.o): wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
Undefined                       first referenced
symbol                             in file
__clzdi2                            Zend/.libs/zend_alloc.o  (symbol belongs to implicit dependency /opt/app/mysql/mysql/lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
__ctzdi2                            Zend/.libs/zend_alloc.o  (symbol belongs to implicit dependency /opt/app/mysql/mysql/lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

From google.com , I found similar problem as me.

[Bug #71006 Zend: symbol referencing errors.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71006)

However, I checked at php.net and found out this problem already patched on Version 7.0.1.

How should I proceed? Please advice.

Comment: Why is this being closed as "can't be reproduced"? I don't see anything in the question to suggest that.

Comment: The warning looks potentially relevant in a way that I don't think it was in the bug; it means you're using a 32-bit library.

Comment: Hello,
GCC will use 64 bit library as I already set CC="gcc -m64". Why would php ignore -m64 and use 32bit library instead?

Comment: how to force gcc to use 64bit library? I cant find how to it anywhere.

Comment: Are you certain that the mysql you have is 64-bit?   You might try specifying a different build-target of `sparc64-sun-solaris2.11`.  That would be the build target for a 64-bit Sparc Solaris.

Comment: I am 100% sure that mysql is 64bit because all file in /path/to/mysql/lib  except *.a is 64 bit. I will inform you the result if i specify "sparc64-sun-solaris2.11" during compilation.